# Can you name an angle using only the labels for two lines extending from a single point WITHOUT mentioning that point?

Tags: geometry, angle

[image]

Is this notation legal or not?

Thank you

Comment: Notation is used to express information in short and easy way. So, if you use this notation and everyone understand this then it will be legal.

Comment: It's certainly not recommended, since if lines A and C crossed, they would form four angles and stating the lines alone it wouldn't be clear which particular angle is being referenced.  I would recommend labeling the points and putting the point that is the vertex in the middle, since that's how it's shown in Geometry textbooks.  An angle CAN be referenced by just one letter if the vertex is labeled as that letter (e.g. Angle D if its vertex is Point D) as long as it is the endpoint of both line segments and not the intersection of two lines (or line segments extended beyond the point).

Comment: That notation makes sense if you also specify which angle is chosen among the four angles formed by the two lines. Adding only the vertex is useless.